# PHPMailer dev-xoauth failed authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, phpmailer

So I've gone through all of the docs on [github - phpmailer xoauth tree](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) to set up my scripts accordingly to use Google's oauth2. I am trying to send an email from the form at [halcyonco.io](http://halcyonco.io/html/contact.html) to myself. The domain name is just to live test this site. I encounter the same error when sending the form locally.

My question is when I submit the form I receive this error:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP pj4sm27148656pbb.29 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO halcyonco.io
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [68.65.121.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO halcyonco.io
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [68.65.121.206]
250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection pj4sm27148656pbb.29 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I have been in touch with Namecheap as I have my hosting and domains through them but after an hour and half they could not help me.

Below is my contact.php script

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = trim($_POST["user_name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["user_email"]);
    $comment = trim($_POST["comment"]);

    if ($name == "" OR $email == "" OR $comment == "") {
        echo '<h3>Please fill out all forms.</h3>';
        exit;
    }

    // SPAM protection 
    foreach ($_POST as $value) {
        if ( stripos($value, 'Content-Type') !== FALSE ) {
            echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";
            exit;
        }
    }


    //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
    //This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

    require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    //Load dependnecies from composer
    //If this causes an error, run 'composer install'
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailerOAuth;

    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Set AuthType
    $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

    //User Email to use for SMTP authentication - Use the same Email used in Google Developer Console
    $mail->oauthUserEmail = "myemail@gmail.com";

    //Obtained From Google Developer Console
    $mail->oauthClientId = "1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com";

    //Obtained From Google Developer Console
    $mail->oauthClientSecret = "123456789";

    //Obtained By running get_oauth_token.php after setting up APP in Google Developer Console.
    //Set Redirect URI in Developer Console as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
    // eg: http://localhost/phpmail/get_oauth_token.php
    $mail->oauthRefreshToken = "1/ABCD12345EFGH6789";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    //For gmail, this generally needs to be the same as the user you logged in as
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'Brandon Smith');

    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'Promethean Fitness Enquiry | ' . $name;

    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->msgHTML = $comment;

    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->Body    = $comment;
    $mail->AltBody = $comment;

    //Attach an image file

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo '<h3>Please ensure you have entered a correct email address.</h3><br>';
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        header("Location: ../html/thanks.html");
            exit;
    }


    //This is a spam protection 
    if ($_POST["user_address"] != "") {
        echo "Your form submission has an error";
        exit;
    }

}



?>
```

Any help on what I need to do in order to fix this would be great.

Comment: With something as bleeding-edge as this, you're best off reporting it directly on GitHub where you're more likely to find maintainers (i.e. me) that know what you're on about! My first suggestion would be to set `SMTPDebug = 4` which will be noisy, but may reveal what's going astray after the second `EHLO`. If you're running dev code like this you might know one of a debugger from the other so you could set a breakpoint in there and see what it's up to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Synchro. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to run a debugger. I'm still pretty new at all of this. I did however set `SMTPDebug = 4` and I can see that it connects with google but as soon as it goes to authenticate it fails. `Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,XOAUTH
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.`
I feel like I'm just one small problem away from fixing this so even though I may be in a little over my head I can hopefully still get this figured out.

Comment: Stick some echo statements around where those debug statements are to see where it's going, see if you can figure out what it's doing wrong.